# PyQt5 QTreeView: как перейти по пути

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть отдельный класс который наследует QTreeView, и в setModel у него QFileSystemModel. Есть в нем функция которой передется путь по типу /mnt/data. Цель: найти и перейти эту папку в QTreeView, но я уже всю голову сломал, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример, демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: @S. Nick проблема в том что я какраз таки и не могу изобразить проблему. Я за этим сюда и обратился

Answer (score 0):

все разобрался

```
 def goto(self, rawpath):
        rootItem = self.indexAt(QPoint(0,0))
        self.setCurrentIndex(rootItem)
        path = rawpath.split("/")
        for item in path:
            if item != "":
                print("ITEM: "+item)
                self.keyboardSearch(item)
                try:
                    self.setExpanded(self.currentIndex(), True)
                except:
                    print("FAIL!")
```